# TCL - Select nth term in a list of floating values

Tags: tcl

Does anyone know of a way to select a **specific value** in a list that consists of **floating values** (i.e. an equivalent method to **Lindex** used for integers in a list)?

Comment: unclear what you're asking. `lindex` extracts the value at a particular list index. It doesn't matter what kind of values are in the list. Please provide an example list of floats that you're having trouble with.

Comment: If you want to **search** something in a list, you should look into [`lsearch`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Tcl's `lindex` command can work on any arbitrary list, but the indices *themselves* have to be either integers or end-relative (e.g., `end-1`). The values in the list can most definitely be floating point numbers (or any other value, including strings and lists and variable names and snippets of code and database handles and …).

```
set theList [list 1.23 2.34 3.45 [expr {4.56 + 5.67}]]
puts [lindex $theList 3]
```

The indices have to be integers because they are logically *counting positions* from the start of the list (or from the end of the list for end-relative, of course). It makes no sense at all to count positions using floating point numbers.

---

If you're trying to find where a floating point number would belong in a sortd list of floating point numbers, the `lsearch` command is the right tool (with the options below).

```
set idx [lsearch -sorted -real -bisect $theList 6.78]

# Now $idx is the index where the value is *or* the index before where it would be inserted
# In particular, $idx+1 indicates the first element later than the value
```

The options above are:

- `-sorted` — Tells the `lsearch` command that the list is sorted (so it can use a binary search algorithm instead of a linear one)
- `-real` — Tells the `lsearch` command that it is using floating point comparisons
- `-bisect` — Tells the `lsearch` command to find the slot for the value (and not return `-1` if it isn't already in there)